# How large is DurandalJS minified?

Tags: durandal

I can't seem to find an answer for this anywhere...

What is the size of the Durandal Core framework (1.2.0 and 2.0.0pre releases) before and after minification?

This would be great information to put back into the official Durandal website.

Comment: I was hoping someone could answer this quickly off the top of their head since you need to download and then build/minify to determine the size. It should really be more obvious since it will help others evaluate the framework.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since there doesn't seem to be a definitive answer to my size question because of the you package and minify a Durandal app, I thought I'd do a ****rough**** comparison by minifying each Durandal JavaScript file individually. Then we can sum up the individual files to get a rough idea of how large Durandal on its own really is.

Here are some guidelines as to what you can expect Durandal to add to your app in terms of size:

### Durandal 1.2.0 (~71Kb raw / ~41Kb minified)

- \durandal

  - app.js          (2,190 bytes / 1,334 bytes minified)
  - composition.js   (10,536 bytes / 6,177 bytes minified)
  - events.js    (4,142 bytes / 2,219 bytes minified)
  - http.js   (988 bytes / 507 bytes minified)
  - messageBox.html  (477 bytes / 477 bytes minified)
  - messageBox.js    (451 bytes / 349 bytes minified)
  - modalDialog.js   (6,293 bytes / 3,571 bytes minified)
  - system.js    (5,480 bytes / 2,711 bytes minified)
  - viewEngine.js    (2,268 bytes / 1,387 bytes minified)
  - viewLocator.js   (3,470 bytes / 2,096 bytes minified)
  - viewModel.js (14,837 bytes / 7,648 bytes minified)
  - viewModelBinder.js   (2,077 bytes / 1,257 bytes minified)
  - widget.js    (4,483 bytes / 2,753 bytes minified)
- \durandal\plugins

  - router.js    (11,440 bytes / 7,019 bytes minified)
- \durandal\widgets\expander

  - controller.js    (685 bytes / 501 bytes minified)
  - view.html    (562 bytes / 562 bytes minified)
- \durandal\transitions

  - entrance.js  (2,488 bytes / 1,221 bytes minified)

### Durandal 2.2.0pre (~171Kb raw / ~66Kb minified)

- \durandal

  - app.js   (4,539 bytes / 1,776 bytes minified)
  - composition.js   (22,836 bytes / 11,361 bytes minified)
  - events.js    (7,461 bytes / 2,226 bytes minified)
  - system.js    (14,560 bytes / 3,987 bytes minified)
  - viewEngine.js    (6,284 bytes / 1,943 bytes minified)
  - viewLocator.js   (6,314 bytes / 2,110 bytes minified)
  - activator.js (21,609 bytes / 8,378 bytes minified)
  - viewModelBinder.js   (5,637 bytes / 2,026 bytes minified)
- \durandal\plugins

  - dialog.js    (15,572 bytes / 5,773 bytes minified)
  - history.js   (11,716 bytes / 4,122 bytes minified)
  - http.js   (2,597 bytes / 509 bytes minified)
  - observable.js    (10,257 bytes / 5,067 bytes minified)
  - router.js    (30,871 bytes / 12,907 bytes minified)
  - serializer.js    (5,171 bytes / 1,355 bytes minified)
  - widget.js    (7,430 bytes / 2,928 bytes minified)
- \durandal\transitions

  - entrance.js  (2,174 bytes / 1,044 bytes minified)

#### Notes:

1. Both versions of Durandal have dependencies on the following additional libraries:

   - RequireJS (~15 Kb minified)
   - RequireJS Text Plug-In (~6.5 Kb minified)
   - KnockoutJS (~15 Kb minified)
   - JQuery (~91 Kb minified)
2. These are just rough estimates based on the minifier I used. Minified sizes could change depending on the utility you use to minify the code.
3. I did not include css or image asset estimates since it's not terribly significant.
4. Since Durandal loads modules on demand using RequireJS, it's possibly that you won't have to incur the full download cost of the framework.
5. The numbers for Durandal 2.0.0pre are subject to change since it hasn't yet been release as of the time of this post.

Hope this helps people.

Cheers,
Richard

Answer (score 0):

The optimization step in Durandal doesn't compile into a single Durandal.js Durandal.min.js file, that's the reason why you can't find an answer to this question.

During optimization your app modules are baked together with Durandal's modules and by default wrapped with almond.js a small loader for AMD modules into ONE file called main-built.js.

In a larger app you might consider lazy-loading some parts of your app in which case almond.js needs to be replaced by require.js. You might even opt for not wrapping your app at all with `almond|require`, but load those upfront.

In addition to requirejs|almond's size, Durandal has a hard dependency on jQuery and knockout and even some minimal CSS for the modal dialogs, so those needs to be taken into account as well.

So if you're working with requirejs, jQuery and knockout anyway the additional size that is added by Durandal is probably a no-brainer for all the SPA capabilities it adds.

If you're more coming from the `backbonejs` world than you might check out http://marionettejs.com/, which of course has its own set of dependecies

> Marionette relies on Underscore, Backbone, jQuery, and various other libraries as its foundation.